# Reordering items with multiple order criteria

Tags: sorting

**Scenario**:

- list of photos
- every photo has the following properties

  - `id`
  - `sequence_number`
  - `main_photo_bit`
- the first photo has the `main_photo_bit` set to `1` (all others are `0`)
- photos are ordered by `sequence_number` (*which is arbitrary*)
- the main photo does not necessarily have the lowest `sequence_number` (before sorting)

See the following table:

```
id, sequence_number, main_photo_bit
1   10               1             
2    5               0             
3   20               0
```

Now you want to change the order by changing the sequence number and main photo bit.

**Requirements after sorting:**

- the `sequence_number` of the first photo is not changed
- the `sequence_number` of the first photo is the lowest
- as less changes as possible

**Examples:**

Example #1 (second photo goes to the first position):

```
id, sequence_number, main_photo_bit
2   10               1             
1   15               0             
3   20               0
```

*This is what happened:*

- *id 1: new `sequence_number` and `main_photo_bit` set to `0`*
- *id 2: old first photo (id 2) `sequence_number` and `main_photo_bit` set to `1`*
- *id 3: nothing happens*

Example #2 (third photo to first position):

```
id, sequence_number, main_photo_bit
3   10               1             
1   20               0             
2   30               0
```

*This is what happened:*

- *id 1: new `sequence_number` bigger than first photo and `main_photo_bit` to `0`*
- *id 2: new `sequence_number` bigger than newly generated second `sequence_number`*
- *id 3: old first photo `sequence_number` and `main_photo_bit` set to `1`*

**What is the best approach to calculate the steps needed to save the new order?**

*Edit:*
The reason that I want as less updates as possible is because I want to sync it to an external service, which is a quite costly operation.
I already got a working prototype of the algorithm, but it fails in some edge cases. So instead of patching it up (which might work -- but it will become even more complex than it is already), I want to know if there are other (better) ways to do it.
In my version (in short) it orders the photos (changing `sequence_number`'s), and swaps the `main_photo_bit`, but it isn't sufficient to solve every scenario.

Comment: Making sure I understand... `Input` to the problem = `1)` Ordered list of the photo records with their _previous_ values, but in the newly desired order.  `2)` Value of the sequence number to be used for the first record (if that info is not available, we can always scan the list until we find the record which has the soon-to-be-flipped main_photo_bit on).  `Output` = a list (ordered or not is TBD) of "Commands" to be applied to individual rows so that a) the new list follow the requirements _and_ b) the number of modified rows is the smallest one.  Is that it ?

Comment: @mjv Yes, that's correct. You have the current ordered list, and you receive a new list from the user in the new desired order. Now you want to save the new order with all _requirements_ met

Comment: @Tim but can **all** photos change order at once? (or at least many at the same time) In your examples just one was selected and moved to the top (and my answer assumed that). But if many can change, then that alone might not work.

Comment: @mgibsonbr **one** photo changes places, but it might be any photo to anywhere, so the first photo can go to the second position, or the second to the third, and so on.

Comment: @Tim ok, thanks for the clarification. I'll think more about it and return later. Just one more question: even if the first photo didn't change place, does the requirement "the `sequence_number` of the first photo is the lowest" still applies? (since it wasn't the lowest before, and that photo didn't change places)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understood, a good solution would not only minimize changes (since **updating**  is the costly operation), but also try to minimize **future changes**, as more and more photos are reordered. I'd start by adding a temporary field `dirty`, to indicate if the row **must** change or not:

```
id, sequence_number, main_photo_bit, dirty
 1         10               1        false
 2          5               0        false
 3         20               0        false
 4         30               0        false
 5         31               0        false
 6         33               0        false
```

If there are rows which `sequence_number` is smaller than the first, they will surely have to change (either to get a higher number, or to become the first). Let's mark them as `dirty`:

```
id, sequence_number, main_photo_bit, dirty
 2          5               0        true
```

(skip this step if it's not really important that the first has the lowest `sequence_number`)

Now let's see the list of photos, as they should be in the result (as per the question, only **one** photo changed places, from anywhere to anywhere). Dirty ones in bold:

> [1, **2**, 3, 4, 5, 6]         # Original ordering
>
> [**2**, **1**, 3, 4, 5, 6]     # Example 1: 2nd to 1st place
>
> [**3**, **1**, **2**, 4, 5, 6] # Example 2: 3rd to 1st place
>
> [1, **2**, 4, **3**, 5, 6]     # Example 3: 3rd to 4th place
>
> [1, **3**, **2**, 4, 5, 6]     # Example 4: 3rd to 2nd place

The first thing to do is ensure the first element has the lowest `sequence_number`. If it hasn't changed places, then it has by definition, otherwise the old first should be marked as dirty, have its `main_photo_bit` cleared, and the new one should receive those values to itself.

At this point, the first element should have a fixed `sequence_number`, and every dirty element can have its value changed at will (since it will have to change anyway, so it's better to change for an useful value). Before proceeding, we must ensure that it's **possible** to solve it with only changing the dirty rows, or if more rows will have to be dirtied as well. This is simply a matter of determining if the interval between every pair of clean rows is big enough to fit the number of dirty rows between them:

```
[10, D, 20, 30, 31, 33]   # Original ordering (the first is dirty, but fixed)

[10, D, 20, 30, 31, 33]   # Example 1: 2nd to 1st place (ok: 10 < ? < 20)
[10, D, D, 30, 31, 33]    # Example 2: 3rd to 1st place (ok: 10 < ? < ? < 30)
[10, D, 30, D, 31, 33]    # Example 3: 3rd to 4th place (NOT OK: 30 < ? < 31)
  [10, D, 30, D, D, 33]   #   must mark 5th as dirty too (ok: 30 < ? < ? < 33)
[10, D, D, 30, 31, 33]    # Example 4: 3rd to 2nd place (ok)
```

Now it's just a matter of assigning new `sequence_number`s to the dirty rows. A naïve solution would be to just increment the previous one, but a better approach would be setting them as **equally spaced** as possible. This way, there are better odds that a future reorder would require less changes (in other words, to avoid problems like Example 3, where more rows than necessary had to be updated since some `sequence_number`s were too close to each other):

> [**10**, **15**, 20, 30, 31, 33]   # Example 1: 2nd to 1st place
>
> [**10**, **16**, **23**, 30, 31, 33]    # Example 2: 3rd to 1st place
>
> [10, **20**, 30, **31**, **32**, 33]    # Example 3: 3rd to 4th place
>
> [10, **16**, **23**, 30, 31, 33]    # Example 4: 3rd to 2nd place

---

Bonus: if you **really** want to push the solution to its limits, do the computation twice - one moving the photo, other having it fixed and moving the surrounding photos - and see which one resulted in less changes. Take example 3A, where instead of "3rd to 4th place" we treat it as "4th to 3rd place" (same sorting results, but different changes):

> [1, **2**, **4**, 3, 5, 6] # Example 3A: 4th to 3rd place
>
> [10, D, D, 20, 31, 33] # (ok: 10 < ? < ? < 20)
>
> [10, **13**, **16**, 20, 31, 33] # One less change

In most cases it can be done (ex.: 2nd to 4th position == 3rd/4th to 2nd/3rd position), whether or not the added complexity is worth the small gain, it's up to you to decide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated the question with some extra information. At first glance it looks good, but I have to do some more work on it to see if it's answer I'm looking for :)

Comment: @Tim I changed the answer completely after your feedback. The old one is still available in the edit history, but AFAIK it's not good enough to meet your requirements, so there's no point in keeping it.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the (edited) answer. I'll look into it, and get back to you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a linked list instead of sequence numbers. Then you can remove a picture from anywhere in the list and reinsert it anywhere in the list, and you only need to change 3 lines in your database file. Main photo bit should be unneccessary, the first photo being implicitly defined by not having any pointers to it.

```
id      next
1       3
2       1
3
```

the order is: 2, 1, 3

user moves picture 3 to position 1:

```
id      next
1       
2       1
3       2
```

new order is: 3, 2, 1